# What are some good Perl modules for flow-based programming on files?

Tags: perl, data-processing

What are some good Perl modules to process files based on configurations?

Basically I am working on taking data files, split them into columns, remove some rows based on some columns, remove unnecessary columns, compare them to baseline (writes where changes have occured) and save a csv of the data and the comments as metadata.

Sample file is:

```
001SMSL22009032020090321024936
002XXXXX20090320102436               010000337 00051     
002XXXXX20090320103525               010000333 00090     
002XXXXX20090320103525               010000333 00090     
002XXXXX20090320103525               010000333 00090     
002XXXXX20090320103525               010000333 00090     
002XXXXX20090320103525               020000333 00090     
009000000009000000000271422122
```

it will compare row by row with another file (baseline)
and some differing rows will be highlighted ( I am use `Tk::DiffText`).

Here is the pipeline where `[is a pipe]`

file -> [split] -> [remove production] -> [sort] -> [compare] -> {user jumps in and writes comments, edits file as needed} -> [save csv] -> [save comments]

The real question is what perl module helps to model and make a pipeline flow like this?
After more research I have found this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow-based_programming.

Comment: What kind of data files?

Comment: You should adjust your question to show a full example of the data file, the input you expect, and the output that you desire. Don't add to the question through comments: make the question better :)

Comment: oops I meant is this better brain d foy.

Comment: He comes onto Stack Overflow is spurts. So I wouldn't expect him around anytime soon.

Comment: You might want to show what the output should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:

[Text::Pipe](http://search.cpan.org/~marcel/Text-Pipe-0.08/lib/Text/Pipe.pm)

[Text::Pipe::Stackable](http://search.cpan.org/~marcel/Text-Pipe-0.08/lib/Text/Pipe/Stackable.pm)

Thank you for helping me clarify my ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, seems that it's nothing Perl cannot handle almost by itself :

taking data files

```
while (<>)
```

split them into columns,

```
my @row = split(/,/);
```

remove some rows based on some columns,

```
next if @row[5] =~ m/black_list_data/;
```

remove unnecessary columns

```
@row = ($row[1], $row[4]);
```

remove unnecessary columns

```
@row = ($row[1], $row[4]);
```

compare them to baseline (writes where changes have occured)

Ok, here you might use [Algorithm::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Algorithm-Diff/)

and save a csv of the data and the comments as metadata.

[Class::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Class-CSV/CSV.pm) or [DBD::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-CSV/lib/DBD/CSV.pm) ?

Comment: Hmm.. the quote CSS style is quite similar to the code style :-(

Comment: I normally leave the quotes as normal text or make them comments in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Sprog](http://sprog.sourceforge.net/).  It is a visual programming engine written in Perl (using Gtk2).  You can create Perl programs by dragging and dropping "gears".  You can also add your own gears (written in Perl, of course).

[image: screen shot of Sprog]

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any Perl implementations of Flow-Based Programming, but I believe Perl 5.8 has made interpreter threads available to Perl coders (someone correct me if I'm wrong!), so it should be relatively straightforward to build an FBP implementation on Perl. See http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html